# How to print missing field in the search result of AWK?

Tags: windows, awk

I want to search a string in Windows Application Event Logs using AWK. The following is the log excerpts:

```
W  05-Nov-14 10:09:36   261 CA_OSC          <I>Process ax_be has finished without having received an explicit termination request from the component manager    </I>
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Line: 1161, File: \MCom\src\OSS\compmgr\src/CaCompPCB.cpp, Process: CaGenericMain (2448)
E  05-Nov-14 10:09:36   17  AY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Process: C:\AXM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:09:36) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessTermination(AppBE,5452) A critical process has
W  05-Nov-14 10:09:37   261 CA_OSC          <I>Process main_ui has finished without having received an explicit termination request from the component manager    </I>
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:37, Line: 1161, File: \MCom\src\OSS\compmgr\src/CaCompPCB.cpp, Process: CaGenericMain (2448)
```

I want to search a string say "ProcessTermination" in the event logs and the search output should be the following:

```
E  05-Nov-14 10:09:36   17  AY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Process: C:\AXM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:09:36) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessTermination(AppBE,5452) A critical process has
```

ie. the logs and all the summary lines when finds a match. 
The Searched string can be in log line or any of the summary lines.
Each line is delimited by new line character and this log file is a .txt file.

So far I have tried the following command:

```
awk -v RS="\n(E|I|W)" "/ProcessTermination/" XA135420_2014_11_05_AppEventLog.txt
```

But in the result, E|I|W is missing . ie. i got the result like

```
  05-Nov-14 10:09:36    17  AY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.    
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Process: C:\AXM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:09:36) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessTermination(AppBE,5452) A critical process has
```

Can anyone help me to list W|E|I (first field of the log line) in the result?

Note: I am using GNU Awk 3.1.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: I test your code sccuess. Cygwin awk 4.1.3

Comment: @ A-Ray :Is there any way to achieve this by GNU AWK?

Comment: @Smij01 cygwin awk is GNU AWK. It's not the cause of your current issue but get a new gawk - yours is WAY out of date and you are missing a lot of extremely useful functionality and bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Load the paragraph in memory with awk

```
awk '/^[EIW]/{if( P ~ /ProcessTermination/)print P;P=""}{P=P"\n"$0}END{if( P ~ /ProcessTermination/)print P}' XA135420_2014_11_05_AppEventLog.txt
```

for field definition you could use `FPAT` instead of `FS` to define a field content and not field separator but i don't know a "`RPAT`"

Comment: Can't we avoid this long command? I have already another command similar to yours:awk '{ if ($1~/^(E|I|W)$/)  { if (print_match) {print line;  print_match=0} line=$0} else {line=line ORS $0}} /ProcessTermination/ {print_match=1} END {if (print_match) {print line;}}' XA135420_2014_11_05_AppEventLog.txt.... But I want to reduce the length of the script some how

Answer (score 0):

By setting RS like you are, you are removing the string matching RS from the record and making your script gawk-specific, none of which are desirable. You could solve the problem by saving each `RT` value and printing it before the next record:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)\\S' '/ProcessTermination/{print gensub(/^\n|\n$/,"","g",p$0)} {p=RT}' file
E  05-Nov-14 10:09:36   17  AY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Process: C:\AXM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:09:36) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessTermination(AppBE,5452) A critical process has
```

The `gensub()` is necessary to remove the newline that every `RT` except the first starts with since the `RS` starts with a newline or start-of-file, and to remove the trailing newline that the last record in the file ends with since it has no subsequent RS-match to suck up the newline it naturally ends in.

The clearer, simpler solution doesn't use RT and works in any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[WEI]/ { check() }
{ buf = buf $0 RS }
END { check() }
function check() {
    if ( index(buf,tgt) ) {
        printf "%s", buf
    }
    buf = ""
}
$
$ awk -v tgt="ProcessTermination" -f tst.awk file
E  05-Nov-14 10:09:36   17  AY_ISC           An error was detected in a process that is monitored by State Manager.
                                                                    Time: 5.11.2014, 10:09:36, Process: C:\AXM\Service\bin\Rep.exe_1976,
                                                                    Text: (05.11.2014 10:09:36) IVS SET: CMonitorThread::ProcessTermination(AppBE,5452) A critical process has
```

Note the use of `index()` above instead of `/.../` or `match()` if you really do want to search for a string, not a regexp.